# .ipa file with mobile provisional certificatie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipa

I have developed my app, and created `ipa file`. I have added the list of devices ID and I downloaded the **certificate**. Now I want to send the `.ipa` file to customer. Is it enough to send the `.ipa` file alone? Or do I have to send the downloaded certificate?

Comment: client uses iphone configuration utility no need of that certificate if via itunes in the windows os need both the ipa file as well as the certificates too

Comment: ipa file alone is enough to install the app in iPhone.

Comment: but the customer says, he need certificate...

Comment: @HarishSaran Can please you confirm with him why there is need of certificate ?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience I can say you can directly send ipa file to customer if his/her device is included in provisioning profile used for creating ipa file.

To verify your provisioning profile is embedded in ipa file just copy ipa anywhere at temporary location rename its extension to zip and extract it. There will be embedded provisioning profile in its content. Remove existing provisioning profile and install that profile just to make sure it is the perfect one if you want to test.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

First open http://www.diawi.com

Now drag and drop your project's .ipa file and your provisioning profile.

After click on send button one LINK is created

Now you can send this link to somewhere and he/she can download your application (Open this link into safari).

hope it will help you.